# Jquery drag and drop based on data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I am newbie to drag and drop functionalities.

Jquery :

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    var DataId = ev.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id');
    alert("Data Id : "+DataId);
    var selected_table =$("#rows .sim-row[data-id='"+DataId+"']");
    //var main_table = selected_table.parentNode;
    alert("Data Id : "+selected_table.html());
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text",selected_table);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    alert("Data Id : "+data.html());
    ev.target.appendChild(data.clone());
}
```

HTML CODE :

```
<div id="content" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
</div>

<div id="rows">
    <table class="sim-row" data-id="1001" id="1001">
        <tr>
            <td class="sim-row-header1 sim-row-edit width100" data-type="title">Main Title</td>                         
        </tr>
     </table>
</div>  

<div class="buttons"  data-id="1001" id="1001" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
            <img id="image"src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/invoice/preview/1001.png" alt="title">Title
        </div>
```

I want to achieve like whenever i am drag and drop image so that time full table must need to add into below div

I have multiple tables which will work like entire table will be dragabble into div.But image must not remove from place.Only its content required to clone or similar.

Right now i am getting below error.But not sure why it's showing me that error.

```
TypeError: data.html is not a function
```

How can i achieve that ?
Any ideas ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Here i want to achieve like img will be drag into content div but img tag must not need to removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/ed5bmth2/1/

```js
allowDrop = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

drag = function(ev) {
  var DataId = ev.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id');
  var selected_table =$("#rows .sim-row[data-id='"+DataId+"']");
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text",DataId);
}

drop = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```css
#content {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<div id="rows">
  <table class="sim-row" data-id="1001" id="1001">
    <tr>
      <td class="sim-row-header1 sim-row-edit width100" data-type="title">Main Title</td>                         
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>  

<div class="buttons"  data-id="1001" id="1001" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
  <img id="image"src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_logo.gif" alt="title">Title
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I see above fiddle also works fine.
But i have image that is inside left panel and div is on the right side.
So whenever i am trying to drag image that time it is change url but not draggable.
So please guide me for this

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle for me, so that I can help you fatser.

Comment: Yeah sure,Give me few minutes

Comment: Thanks,May be jquery has not loaded or may be any other issue that's why it was not working before.Now it's working fine.
I need one more help from you.Isn't possible like whatever times i am drag image but image must not be dragged.Instead of that table need to be dragged.

Comment: @AnkitDoshi . Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/ed5bmth2/2/ .Please update the question & if you are satisfied please accept & up vote the answer.

Comment: I  get solution for this question.But you helped me a lot.Thanks for that and going to up vote now

Comment: Sorry,Due to less reputation not able to upvote now.But will do once get some good reputation.